# JavaScript dropdown box filter based upon option value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to filter database with options from a drop down using JavaScript to change the values to filter by. However dropdown is filtering the value between the option tags instead of the value inside the option tag. I've been looking around to find an answer to this issue but can't seem to find a solution. Below is a snippet of my script.

**JavaScript**

```
function showRoad(value) {
var xhttp;
if (value == "") {
    document.getElementByID("txtHint").innerHTML ="";
    return;
}
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "road.php?q="+value, true);
xhttp.send();
```

}

```
echo '<select class="form-control" style="width:auto" onchange="showRoad(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" name"showRoad">';
echo '<option>Select Road Name</option>';
//I have these generated by a php while loop but I put them in HTML for easy reference
<option value"LN">Louisville and Nashvile Railroad (CSXT) (LN)</option>
<option value"MTW">Marinette, Tomahawk and Western Railroad (MTW)</option>
<option value"CAGX">MHC (ConAgra) (CAGX)</option>
<option value"MCEX">Midwest Railcar Equiptment Co. (MCEX)</option>
```

I want the dropdown to fliter by LN, MTW, CAGX etc as it stands right now it's filtering by the data between the option tags

Comment: Why you are passing value at onchange already but on your function you still trying to get the selectObject.value again ?

Comment: That might be left over from when I was trying something to make it work as intended.

Comment: Hi you missed `=` near `value="LN"` do same for all options. That's the reason its taking `text` as value not `value`

Answer (score 0):

Start by really simplifying things.

In your example, I think

```
xhttp.open("GET", "road.php?q="+str, true);
```

is supposed to be something like

```
xhttp.open("GET", "road.php?q="+value, true);
```

It's not clear where that rogue `str` is coming from.

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector('select');
selectElement.addEventListener("change", (event) => console.log(event.target.value));
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Select Road Name</option>
  <option value="LN">Louisville and Nashvile Railroad (CSXT) (LN)</option>
  <option value="MTW">Marinette, Tomahawk and Western Railroad (MTW)</option>
  <option value="CAGX">MHC (ConAgra) (CAGX)</option>
  <option value="MCEX">Midwest Railcar Equiptment Co. (MCEX)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: str was one of the parameters that was part of the javascript function. I've corrected it. It's still not working